# Data binding problem return by java mvc controller using api read

Tags: java, spring-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                           
                    transport: {
                         read: {
                             url: function(options) 
                             {   return "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/charts";
                                         },
                            
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET"
                        }
                        },
                            
                            schema:{
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        id: { type: "number" },
                                        fullName : { type: "string" },
                                        address: { type: "string" },
                                        email : { type: "string" },
                                        password: { type: "string" },
                                        designation: { type: "string" },
                                        salary: { type: "number" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            aggregate: [ { field: "fullName", aggregate: "count" },
                                
                                          { field: "salary", aggregate: "sum" }
                                          ]
                             
                       ,pageSize: 8 },
                        sortable: true,
                        scrollable: false,
                       pageSize: 5,
                       pageSizes: true,
                        hieght:20,
                         pageable: {
                
           pageSizes: [4, 6,10,"all"],
           buttonCount: 5
                },
     columns: [
                   { field: "id", title: "ID", width: 180  },
                   { field: "fullName", title: "Name",width:300,
                    template: "<div style=color:red>#=fullName#</div>" ,footerTemplate: "Total Count: #=count#"  },
                     { field: "address", title: "Address",width:300 },
                      { field: "email", title: "Email",width:200},
                      { field: "password", title: "Password" ,width:200},
                            { field: "designation", title: "Designation" ,width:300},
                            { field: "salary", title: "Salary" ,width:200,footerTemplate: "Total Sum: #=sum#"},
                            { width:200,
                              template: "<a class='k-button' href='/Home/Index'>Redirect</a>"   }
                            
                        ]
                    });
```

i want to set these data set in json formate return by my java mvc controller..
i am try to bind json data set retuned by mvc controller and show these data set in Kendo ui grid but the data is not set in grid and empty grid is shown here is my code...

Comment: It is not readable format of the post. Edit it and clarify your problem, add code necessary to reproduce it.